# Is there a Stack Exchange site for poker?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site — existing or planned — for poker players?

Comment: Why don't you search it ?

Comment: @Sarang: Good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, one has been proposed:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3425/poker

Answer (score 5):

While you wait for the poker-specific proposal to mature, note that poker [is considered on-topic at the Board and Card Games SE](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/poker-is-it-on-topic) as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Stack Exchange Home Page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to search through the existing sites.

If there is no Stack Exchange site on that subject,  you can search [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) to see if anyone has created a proposal for one to be created.